# How to HOST javafx Application

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, javafx

I have developed application in Netbeans IDE 6.9 Using javafx Script based Application. i can able to build and run using IDE successfully .

But My requirement  is  i have to Run Same App in different machine where No Netbeans IDE.I have **Jar file** which developed by netbeans . How to launch that in different machine.

Am newbie for java .Please Guide me to install my app

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a JRE is installed on this machine you can launch the jar with this shell command:

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

I am not familiar with javafx but you might need to include javafx libraries in your command (and maybe install them on the target machine before). See [Launching JavaFX script via a jar file](http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/archives/javafx-run-jar)

Comment: Thanks Matt Handy. I ll check this.

Comment: it shows error as can't find my .main class . so program will exit.

Comment: handy : any tool to convert jar to exe

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290914/conversion-of-class-to-jar-and-class-to-exe/5290979#5290979) for some options.

Answer (score 0):

Launching javafx quit simple.....
   instead of using jar file .We can Find **JNLP files** which is inside the dist folder of your project.Using that We can lunch our app.